# C#: same-signature methods/constructors and named arguments

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Suppose for instance I'm defining a `Complex` class for representing complex numbers. I would like to define two constructors, so that I can write for example:

```
Complex z1 = new Complex(x: 4, y: 3);
Complex z2 = new Complex(r: 2, theta: Math.PI / 4);
```

However, I cannot define the constructors like this:

```
public Complex(double x, double y) { ... }
public Complex(double r, double theta) { ... }
```

because both constructors would have the same signature, which is not allowed. But in C# 4 I can write this, using an optional argument:

```
public Complex(double x, double y) { ... }
public Complex(double r, double theta, bool unused=true) { ... }
```

It works, I can then use the above constructor calls as intended. The sole purpose of the `unused` argument is to make the signatures different; it's totally unused, both when defining and when calling the constructor.

To me this seems to be a an ugly trick: is there any better option?

Comment: That doesn't really buy you anything - you have no control over which one gets called with two double arguments (it'll always be the same one).

Comment: You're right, but my purpose is to explicitly select which constructor I want to use thanks to named arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the constructor private and have a static factory style function.

```
public static Complex CreateComplexPolar(double r, double theta);
public static Complex CreateComplex(double x, double y);
```

You can do validation on the inputs based on what they should be.

Another possibility would be to create a type that encapsulates the inputs and use constructors as you previously mentioned.

```
public struct PolarCoordinates
{
  public double Rho;
  public double Theta;
}

public struct CartesianCoordinates
{
  public double X;
  public double Y;
}

public Complex(PolarCoordinates pc);
public Complex(CartesianCoordinates cc);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a static method to create the class, say `Complex::FromDouble` and `Complex::FromDoubleAndTheta`.

You can go one step further and make the real constructor private  in order to force that construction.

For example, see TimeSpan's [FromDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromdays.aspx) and [FromHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx).

p.s.
Use better names :)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be to make one constructor (double, double) and the other could be double, Func.

```
public Complex(double x, double y) { ... }
public Complex(double r, Func<double> theta) { ... }
```

It looks like in your example from above that you are doing a calculation and the result of that calculation is the 2nd value for that constructor. If that was always the case then you could just make it a Func parameter instead. Kind of a hack, but it might be better than having an optional 3rd parameter that does nothing.

Comment: Actually, `theta` is just an angle. π/4 is not really a *calculation*, just a convenient way of specifying an angle value. I could as well have written something like `0.79`. So the second argument should really be a double.

Comment: I see your point. Although you could still use it in this way to differentiate the constructors. Still a hack though. Have you thought about a parameterless constructor and then using properties for the various parameter combinations? Either that or I suppose you could make a base class and make each constructor a separate class that inherits from the base.

Comment: Parameterless constructor properties: what worries me is that you can create an “uninitialized” object. Sub-classing: a class should represent a *kind of objects*, not a *kind of constructor*... So again it's a hack...

Comment: Private constructor with static factory as mentioned above may be the best choice. It still feels like there should be a more eloquent solution though.